# How do I automatically close an overlay on a website through VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, overlay, html, autofill

I was writing code to autofill data on a website but an overlay prevents me from doing so. I have opened the page in a web browser. I wanted to know if there is any way to close the overlay from VB.NET.

Here is the webpage:
 https://pgi.billdesk.com/pgidsk/pgijsp/citicard/citibank_card.jsp

And this is the overlay:

[image: Image of Overlay]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to automatically fill out payment information on a webpage from a VB.NET application? I would be wary of the potential security issues this could raise.

Comment: @Christopher I was just trying it out! I do know the Security Issues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the thing!

```
Dim DvOvr = PayBillsBrowser.Document.GetElementById("overlay-wrapper")
If DvOvr IsNot Nothing Then
    DvOvr.Style = "Display:none
End If
```